# NFS read/writes since startup

Tags: nfs, io, iostat

I'd like to retrieve the total number of kilobytes read/written for each NFS mount point.

Using the following commands, I'm able to see the current throughput for each NFS mount point in kB/S.

```
iostat -nk
```

Alternatively:

```
nfsiostat
```

Is there a way to tell iostat or nfsiostat to return the total number of kilobytes since boot?

(Much like the last two columns of `iostat -k`)

```
Device:    tps    kB/read/s    kB/wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn
sda        17.69  234.75       30.82        2760421    362433
```

Comment: What OS are you using? My ```iostat``` from the Linux ```systat``` package shows the stats since boot by default.

Comment: Centos, do your NFS stats appear in x per second? Or do you have total bytes since boot?

Comment: The output of a plain ```iostat``` command looks like yours. It shows kb written per second (measured since boot) and absolut kb written since boot. Using  ```iostat -d 5 2``` would print two reports. The first one is again the "since boot" report. The second one for the next "5 seconds report".

Answer (score 0):

By assuming you use Linux client, you can use **mountstats** command, which prints statistics per mount point:

```
$ mountstats /mnt
Stats for xxxx:/ mounted on /mnt:
  NFS mount options: rw,vers=4.1,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,namlen=255,acregmin=3,acregmax=60,acdirmin=30,acdirmax=60,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=a.b.c.d,local_lock=none
  NFS server capabilities: caps=0x3ffdf,wtmult=512,dtsize=32768,bsize=0,namlen=255
  NFSv4 capability flags: bm0=0xfcffbfff,bm1=0x40fdbe3e,bm2=0x800,acl=0x3,sessions,pnfs=LAYOUT_NFSV4_1_FILES
  NFS security flavor: 1  pseudoflavor: 0

NFS byte counts:
  applications read 602253119 bytes via read(2)
  applications wrote 1750 bytes via write(2)
  applications read 0 bytes via O_DIRECT read(2)
  applications wrote 0 bytes via O_DIRECT write(2)
  client read 552781120 bytes via NFS READ
  client wrote 1750 bytes via NFS WRITE

RPC statistics:
  634086 RPC requests sent, 634061 RPC replies received (0 XIDs not found)
  average backlog queue length: 0

READ:
    164908 ops (26%) 
    avg bytes sent per op: 208  avg bytes received per op: 3457
    backlog wait: 0.112984  RTT: 0.523801   total execute time: 0.651181 (milliseconds)
GETATTR:
    156471 ops (24%)    4 retrans (0%)  0 major timeouts
    avg bytes sent per op: 191  avg bytes received per op: 267
    backlog wait: 0.202849  RTT: 0.257179   total execute time: 0.496686 (milliseconds)
LAYOUTGET:
    156323 ops (24%) 
    avg bytes sent per op: 236  avg bytes received per op: 215
    backlog wait: 0.007536  RTT: 5.057336   total execute time: 5.319857 (milliseconds)
OPEN_NOATTR:
    156321 ops (24%) 
    avg bytes sent per op: 260  avg bytes received per op: 347
    backlog wait: 0.007126  RTT: 0.473941   total execute time: 0.489806 (milliseconds)
```

on RedHat based system, it's a part of nfs-util package. In debian based probably in nfs-common.

Comment: Also, there's `nfsstats` command.